# accessing the filesystem of the host from a docker container running in --privileged mode: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Tags: linux, docker, lvm

I'm running a systemed docker container with ssh conection and now want to mount the host filesystem to gain access to it. ( don't worry this is just for demonstration purpose)

If i do

```
mount /dev/vda2 /mnt/dockerhost/
mount: /mnt/dockerhost: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

So i can mount /dev/vda1 and see grub files and anything

This is what i tried yet:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
vda    252:0    0   30G  0 disk 
├─vda1 252:1         1G  0 part 
└─vda2 252:2    0   29G  0 part

fdisk -l 
Disk /dev/vda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xda24a492

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *       2048  2099199  2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/vda2       2099200 62914559 60815360  29G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/dm-0: 27 GiB, 28949086208 bytes, 56541184 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                      27G  2.6G   25G  10% /
tmpfs                        64M     0   64M   0% /dev
shm                          64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/almalinux-root   27G  2.6G   25G  10% /etc/hosts
tmpfs                       882M  8.1M  874M   1% /run
```

Any idears how i can mount this lvm partition ? To Meantion the host machine is a virtual machine running alma-linux

thx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly mount LVM partitions, neither in a container nor even in the host. They may contain multiple nested volumes that need to be mapped to /dev/dm devices first (the host OS has already done this), and then those dm devices will have filesystems that can be mounted. (This is the whole point of LVM, really.) See the `lvs` command for example.

You also cannot mount the same filesystem twice. If the container needs to access a filesystem that's already mounted on the host, then there's no point in trying to mount it from the container again – instead the folder should be passed into the container as a bind mount.

Comment: Thx for ur input  i see i see can you tell me how i map them ? I found nothing on the internet yet